# Failed address validation With Automatic Customer Group Assigment enabled

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, paypal-express, vat

So again i am badly hit by Magento today.

I have enabled the "Automatic Assignment To Customer Group" for my VAT validation process to assign special customer group to those who has validated their VAT.

That part is working fine.

Now i have added the Paypal express checkout to Store, and trying to place an order but on order review page when i accept the Terms and conditions and select the shipping, now by hitting the button to place order it is giving me error with "Failed address validation".

So disabling the "Automatic Group Assignment" it is working fine, but as you see i required this option for my VAT thing so cant disable.

So I have also tried to disable Skip Order Review Step but still the error is there.

Now my question is how i can figure this out, and make both the things work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by , and created a patch for this please find the patch on my [Git Repository](https://github.com/shoaibgits/paypaexpress-patch)